# How to implement texture slicing

Tags: c#, mathematics, graphics, windows-forms

I'm making a simple game in C# and **i'm trying to slice my UI images into 9 smaller rectangles**, so the image doesn't get stretched when drawing to different resolutions, but i'm having lots of problems with my code.

I have the following method for slicing an image:

```
public RectangleF[] SliceRectangle (RectangleF rectangle, float LeftPadding, float RightPadding, float TopPadding, float BottomPadding)
{
    var x = rectangle.X;
    var y = rectangle.Y;
    var w = rectangle.Width;
    var h = rectangle.Height;

    var middleWidth = w - LeftPadding - RightPadding;
    var middleHeight = h - TopPadding - BottomPadding;
    var bottomY = y + h - BottomPadding;
    var rightX = x + w - RightPadding;
    var leftX = x + LeftPadding;
    var topY = y + TopPadding;

    var patches = new RectangleF[]
    {
        new RectangleF(x,      y,        LeftPadding,  TopPadding),      // top left
        new RectangleF(leftX,  y,        middleWidth,  TopPadding),      // top middle
        new RectangleF(rightX, y,        RightPadding, TopPadding),      // top right

        new RectangleF(x,      topY,     LeftPadding,  middleHeight),    // left middle
        new RectangleF(leftX,  topY,     middleWidth,  middleHeight),    // middle
        new RectangleF(rightX, topY,     RightPadding, middleHeight),    // right middle

        new RectangleF(x,      bottomY,  LeftPadding,  BottomPadding),   // bottom left
        new RectangleF(leftX,  bottomY,  middleWidth,  BottomPadding),   // bottom middle
        new RectangleF(rightX, bottomY,  RightPadding, BottomPadding)    // bottom right
    };

    return patches;
}
```

And then i draw the sliced image like this:

```
public void Render (Graphics graphics)
{
    sprite.rectangle = new RectangleF(0, 0, 512, 512);

    var destination_slices = sprite.SliceRectangle(rectangle: sprite.rectangle, left: 32, right: 480, top: 32, bottom: 480);
    var source_slices = sprite.SliceRectangle(rectangle: new RectangleF(0, 0, sprite.texture.Width, sprite.texture.Height), left: 32, right: 224, top: 16, bottom: 48);

    for (int i = 0; i < source_slices.Length; i++)
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(sprite.texture, destination_slices[i], source_slices[i], GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Debug.Log(source_slices[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the result that is printed by the "Render" method:

```
Top left:   X = 0,   Y = 0,  Width = 32,  Height = 16
Top middle: X = 32,  Y = 0,  Width = 192, Height = 16
Top right:  X = 224, Y = 0,  Width = 32,  Height = 16

Middle left:  X = 0,   Y = 16, Width = 32,  Height = 32
Middle:       X = 32,  Y = 16, Width = 192, Height = 32
Middle Right: X = 224, Y = 16, Width = 32,  Height = 32

Bottom left:   X = 0,   Y = 48, Width = 32,  Height = 16
Bottom middle: X = 32,  Y = 48, Width = 192, Height = 16
Bottom right:  X = 224, Y = 48, Width = 32,  Height = 16
```

Now, the problem is that this method is producing completely wrong results:

- When changing the rectangle values, the slices gets scaled incorectly.
- The image slices are not sized correctly and some parts of the image are missing, specially when changing the padding values.
- I believe the padding is what is making the slices draw incorrectly, so i would like to know what values they should have.

Some specifications:

- The size of the image i'm drawing is 256 by 64 pixels.
- The area i want to draw the image is 512 by 512 pixels.

I tried lots of different values and combinations, but could not make this method work,
so i'm hoping someone here tests the code and help me find a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer (I cannot make the time right now!), but I solve a similar problem with a dedicated struct for a 9slice. It takes outer dimensions and margins and turns them into 16 points, which are then used by the renderer to create the 9 quads (rects in your case) to actually draw. https://github.com/htmlcoderexe/3DGame/blob/a364bb1dc7f7edf6e6aa47a6d02502ca4479a244/GUI/Renderer.cs#L93 The code that uses this data structure is in RenderFrame inside GFXUtility in the same folder, you can follow it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'll test it later. I would appreciate if someone could post a direct answer to my question here too as i found this code a bit complicated .

Comment: What are the parameters passed to the region rectangles constructor? Are those the direct padding values? Is the result you've shared for the destination or the source? What is `source_patch`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The parameters passed are the padding values and the result i have shared is for the source slices. The source patch is a wrong name i typed, sorry.

Comment: Then why `right: 224`? If your source image is 256 pixels wide, and left padding is 32 pixels, and right padding is 224, there would be no texture left for the middle piece? Yet this is not what your results show, so it's not clear if the provided code actually produces the output shown.

Comment: I don't know if i understand you but there is 32 more pixels before the left: 32 and 32 more pixels after right: 224. I image the padding as some sort of lines in the texture.

Comment: Then your previous comment isn't true, as the `right` value is not the direct padding size, but instead coordinates that you (assumedly?) calculate the actual padding values from.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the padding values are basically coordinates.

Comment: Okay, and how do you calculate those padding values? Since the region only gets those coordinates and no size, how does `TextureRegion` know that `RightPadding` should be `32` pixels, as all it gets is `224`?

Comment: I'm using a method to calculate the distance between the padding value and some border related to it, then the value is used, for example, as the "middle" size. I'm working with several different code and the one that got me the closest to solving the problem was the one i posted in  this question, so i would like some help to fix it.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact output of debug,log for source slices and maybe also destination slices? Maybe add a breakpoint right after the log statement so the program pauses instead of spamming the log 60 times per second or whatever the framerate is. I strongly suspect that the code you provided wants the bottom/right paddings as relative and not absolute values - I tried to "run" the function in my head with your suggested input and it did give the garbage values. As an example, you might want to have left/right as 32 and top/bottom as 16 in your source slices.